# Los links del menú situado en el head de mi ejemplo para cambiar el foco directamente a contenedores del body no funcionan del todo bien

Tags: html, css, responsive

Tengo algunos problemas que no consigo resolver con esta página de pruebas que estoy realizando.

En la página pretendo tener una cabecera y pie fijo y un cuerpo central en el que hallan tres `article` cuya altura mínima para cada uno de ellos se extienda entre la cabecera y el pie fijo.

Tengo un menú en la cabecera con el que pretendo poder posicionarme directamente en cada uno de los tres `article` definidos: Inicio, Ejemplos y Contacto.
No consigo que al clickear en los enlaces los artículos ocupen correctamente toda la posición central. Se meten por debajo de la cabecera y/o el pie según la resolución que utilice.

Con la resolución con la que estoy desarrollando (1920 x 1080) se ve más o menos bien, pero cuando la resolución es bastante menor el problema se hace más visible.

La verdad es que quería intentar montar este esqueleto lo más responsive posible en esta resolución y después pensar en las modificaciones `@media` para adaptarlo a otras resoluciones, pero ya no sé si este es un buen enfoque.
Cualquier sugerencia para mejorarlo será bien recibida.

```js
function OcultarResultado() {

  document.getElementById("examples-resultado").style.display = "none";;
  document.getElementById("parrafo1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("parrafo2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("parrafo3").style.display = "none";

  return true;
}

function MuestraResultado(numParrafo) {

  OcultarResultado();
  document.getElementById("examples-resultado").style.display = "block";;
  document.getElementById("parrafo" + numParrafo).style.display = "block";

  return true;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #efefef;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header,
nav,
aside,
section,
article,
footer {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Tahoma';
}

header {
  background: #B7B9B8;
  /* gris */
}

article {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 90%;
}

footer {
  background: #F36623;
  /* naranja */
}


/****************** CABECERA **************************************/

#main-header {
  background-color: #ffc52e;
  opacity: 0.95;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 5vh;
  /*    min-height: 50px;*/
}

#logo-header {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#title-header {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-header {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-header nav ul {
  padding-right: 3px;
  font-size: .6em;
}

#nav-header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#nav-header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-header nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #0b76a6;
  color: white;
}


/******************************* MAIN ******************************/

#main-content {
  margin-top: 6vh;
  margin-bottom: 6vh;
}


/* ------------------------------Articulo 1: Presentacion --------------------- */

#welcome-article {
  background: #AD1717;
  /*rojo burdeos */
}

#welcome-content {
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-family: Verdana;
  min-height: 86vh;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* ------------------------------Articulo 2: Ejemplos --------------------- */

#examples-article {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: #EBCCC2;
  /*rosa */
  min-height: 70vh;
  padding: 10px;
}

#examples-content {
  width: 55%;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

#div-aside {
  width: 35%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #ffc52e;
  /*naranja pálido*/
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#div-aside nav ul {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 95%;
}

#div-aside nav ul li {
  line-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  color: #551a8b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#div-aside nav li:hover {
  color: white;
}

#div-aside nav ul li a {
  color: #551a8b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#div-aside nav ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}

#div-aside ul li:focus,
#div-aside ul li:focus a {
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#div-aside ul li:hover,
#div-aside ul li:hover:focus a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.05em;
}

#examples-resultado {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#examples-resultado header {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

#body-examples-resultado {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}


/* ------------------------------Articulo 3: Contacto --------------------- */

#contacto-article {
  min-height: 86vh;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}


/* ******************************* PIE **************************** */

#footer {
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  /*min-height: 50px;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#ValidacionW3C {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3%;
}

#copyright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3%;
  font-size: .5em;
}


/* ******************************* PARA USO INDIVIDUAL **************************** */

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.oculto {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mi primera página con dificultad</title>

<body id="start-body">
  <!-- inicio header -->
  <header id="main-header">
    <div id="logo-header">
      LOGO HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="title-header">
      TITULO HEADER
    </div>
    <!-- inicio nav -->
    <div id="nav-header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#welcome-article">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#examples-article">Ejemplos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contacto-article">Contacto</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- fin nav -->

  </header>
  <!-- fin header -->



  <!-- inicio section principal-->
  <section id="main-content">

    <article id="welcome-article">

      <div id="welcome-content">
        <p> PAGINA DE PRESENTACION </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article id="examples-article">

      <div id="examples-content">
        <p class="center">Examples-content</p><br>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id aliquam quaerat ipsa dolore quidem magni beatae, consequatur voluptate excepturi animi hic expedita officia corporis sunt aspernatur pariatur alias iste cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ex assumenda eaque, reiciendis blanditiis architecto sed dolor, unde officia natus. Quas debitis repellendus esse officia provident nihil molestiae magni omnis!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est </p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, nihil, ratione? Pariatur aliquid animi quis eum odit perspiciatis consectetur dolorum maiores itaque, ab rem nihil eius corrupti laborum beatae sunt!</p>
      </div>
      <aside id="div-aside">
        <div id="nav-div-aside">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li tabindex="0" onclick="javascript:MuestraResultado('1')"> <a>Parrafo1</a> </li>
              <li tabindex="0" onclick="javascript:MuestraResultado('2')"> <a>Parrafo2</a> </li>
              <li tabindex="0" onclick="javascript:MuestraResultado('3')"> <a>Parrafo3</a> </li>

            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="oculto" id="examples-resultado">
          <header>
            <p class="center">Header examples-resultado</p>
          </header>

          <div id="body-examples-resultado">

            <p class="center">body-examples-resultado</p><br>

            <p id="parrafo1" class="oculto">PARRAFO1: <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id aliquam quaerat ipsa dolore quidem magni beatae, consequatur voluptate excepturi animi hic expedita officia corporis sunt aspernatur pariatur alias iste cum?Lorem ipsum
              dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ex assumenda eaque, reiciendis blanditiis architecto sed dolor. </p>

            <p id="parrafo2" class="oculto">PARRAFO2: <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores corrupti, qui reprehenderit assumenda optio soluta accusantium, voluptas ad recusandae ratione sit cupiditate. Beatae in labore magni iste perferendis dolorem,
              consequuntur? Soluta facilis quis excepturi animi eveniet, nihil, nisi rerum officiis minima quidem incidunt iste est, sint sit deleniti ex! Deleniti voluptatem, hic, ipsam labore reiciendis vero enim ratione possimus delectus. Ab omnis
              error cumque perferendis atque, vero architecto, corrupti corporis veritatis nesciunt natus quos doloremque fugiat facere deleniti nostrum accusamus expedita! Numquam magnam odit similique natus accusantium debitis deleniti sapiente? Dolorum
              expedita quis minima molestiae porro dolore temporibus, eius ullam accusamus asperiores fugiat quia doloremque in, rerum nostrum magni, neque vitae dolores, nesciunt id sint. Id totam fugit praesentium molestias?

              <p id=parrafo3 class="oculto">PARRAFO3: <br>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam rem maxime omnis ipsum quidem praesentium natus saepe dolorum mollitia, nisi porro corporis quod doloremque dolore, molestias, reiciendis voluptatem id ad.
                Aperiam ipsam quaerat, excepturi, eum vitae quo animi veritatis voluptatem nostrum dolorem, quod praesentium quae! Ipsum voluptatem et ducimus explicabo eum totam officiis porro accusamus! Aspernatur cum cupiditate delectus provident?
                Repudiandae saepe neque, dolor aspernatur, est consectetur deserunt officiis quidem? Exercitationem nisi totam ut cum dolore sit nesciunt sapiente ratione dicta, blanditiis excepturi architecto quod voluptas voluptatum odit quasi laudantium.
                Iure labore voluptatem animi illo quibusdam dolorem voluptates ducimus aperiam vel accusamus aliquid sint itaque adipisci sed culpa soluta, impedit quaerat temporibus! Expedita repellat, facilis totam quae harum ullam dicta. Ipsa laboriosam
                quas corrupti libero necessitatibus fugiat. Neque, quod. Similique nobis dolorum quis modi eaque, doloribus autem sint recusandae nemo ex officiis facere reprehenderit eveniet ducimus, eius amet rem. Ut. Accusantium fuga perferendis, iure
                ipsum nostrum tempora odio, quas repellat aut quaerat, pariatur eveniet consectetur reprehenderit quos impedit numquam culpa. Inventore, quidem excepturi fuga! Odio dolores eum libero iusto, voluptate? Distinctio quisquam laborum voluptatum
                voluptatibus, nesciunt soluta illo, vero, repellendus repudiandae eum adipisci perferendis. Amet omnis fugiat tempore voluptate, possimus cum, aut quibusdam, cupiditate veritatis numquam, vero eos labore esse. Neque totam dolores corrupti
                consequatur quaerat ab velit dignissimos magnam eaque nemo, vel iusto rem cupiditate explicabo temporibus debitis nihil placeat id tempora ut impedit pariatur natus minima odit doloremque. Quo ab perspiciatis architecto rem esse. Veritatis
                amet veniam cupiditate tenetur voluptatibus quaerat animi ratione ad doloremque adipisci deleniti, sed perspiciatis velit, assumenda quidem facere, mollitia rem nulla nam dolore. Totam, voluptatem voluptatibus. Repellendus quae fugiat
                placeat hic similique doloremque ducimus quaerat at eveniet quo officia nobis consequuntur tempora, aliquam, dicta laboriosam! Fugit, numquam. Repellat, cupiditate modi recusandae animi illum.
              </p>


          </div>

        </div>
      </aside>
    </article>
    <article id="contacto-article">
      <p class="center">contacto-article</p><br>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rerum nemo aliquam, non inventore soluta voluptatibus fuga. Impedit veniam, similique quod maiores libero molestias, quasi laboriosam, asperiores commodi nihil harum odit?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id aliquam quaerat ipsa dolore quidem magni beatae, consequatur voluptate excepturi animi hic expedita officia corporis sunt aspernatur pariatur alias iste cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Debitis ex assumenda eaque, reiciendis blanditiis architecto sed dolor, unde officia natus. Quas debitis repellendus esse officia provident nihil molestiae magni omnis!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
        dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id aliquam quaerat ipsa dolore quidem magni beatae, consequatur voluptate excepturi animi hic expedita officia corporis sunt aspernatur pariatur alias iste cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Debitis ex assumenda eaque, reiciendis blanditiis architecto sed dolor, unde officia natus. Quas debitis repellendus esse officia provident nihil molestiae magni omnis!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
        dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est </p>
    </article>

  </section>
  <!-- fin section principal-->


  <!-- inicio footer -->
  <footer id="footer">
    <div id="ValidacionW3C">
      <p>
        <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
          <img src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="¡CSS Válido!" />
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="copyright">
      <p>&copy; de los textos, Fulanito de tal , 2021</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- fin footer -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yo lo que haria en tu caso seria tener tres secciones: header, main y footer. Luego aplicaria display flex al body (o a un div encerrando los tres elementos) flex direction column para que se apilen en columna; justify content between para que header y footer se peguen al top y al bottom respectivamente y te va a quedar main centrado, al cual le aplicass grow 1 asi toma ell resto del espacio disponible. De esta manera no tendras solapamientos

Answer (score 0):

Encontré solución al problema del encabezado de página fijo que se superpone a los anclajes en mi página en este link [Fixed page header overlaps in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors).

Utilizando scroll-padding-top consigo solucionar el problema.